# TypeError: Invalid Version: undefined using Gulp in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, gulp

I'm new to all of this Node.js, npm, Bower and Gulp stuff so I'm trying to start get familiar with it.  I started by installing Node.js which seemed to go smoothly.  I then installed gulp both globally and locally according to what I've found online:

```
> npm install --global gulp
> npm install --save-dev gulp
```

The second one was of course done in the directory of my project and it did indeed update my package.json file.

So I now have a package.json file that looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "typescripttestapp",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.html",
 "dependencies": {
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "del": "^1.2.0",
   "gulp": "^3.9.0",
   "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
   "gulp-copy": "0.0.2",
   "gulp-typescript": "^2.7.8"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC"
}
```

I've also installed Task Runner Explorer in Visual Studio.  I have the following gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task("default",function(){});
```

However, any time I try to refresh the Task Runner Explorer, I get the following error in the Output Window:

> Failed to load
>   "F:\Business\Development\TestSandBoxes\TypeScriptTestApp\TypeScriptTestApp\gulpfile.js"...
>   C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\semver\semver.js:281
>       throw new TypeError('Invalid Version: ' + version);
>             ^ TypeError: Invalid Version: undefined
>       at new SemVer (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\semver\semver.js:281:11)
>       at SemVer.compare (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\semver\semver.js:348:13)
>       at compare (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\semver\semver.js:571:31)
>       at Function.gt (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\semver\semver.js:600:10)
>       at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:99:14)
>       at Liftoff. (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:192:16)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:17:3)
>       at Liftoff. (C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:185:9)
>       at C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:159:9
>       at C:\Users\rodd_harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:91:14

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

By some experimenting, I found that gulp will run **if** I do `gulp -v` first.  If I open a command prompt and go to my project directory and just run `gulp` I get the same error as I do from Task Runner.  However, if, as I said, I do the `gulp -v` first, then run `gulp` it works.

It would still be nice to know if I've got something configured wrong because at present, I'm still unable to set this up with Task Runner Explorer.

Comment: try `npm cache clean` and reinstall gulp

Comment: Would you uninstall glup first or reinstall overtop of the existing install?

Comment: That didn't work.  I uninstalled gulp both locally and globally and then did what you recommended.   I then reinstalled both globally and locally and I get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue, make sure you have run **npm init** in the base directory of your gulp file and then install gulp locally **npm install gulp --save-dev**.  This seems to resolve it for me when running gulp in Visual Studio Code.